# Euclidean Algorithm for Modular Inverse, with negative numbers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I might be on to something quite simple which I'm failing to see, while calculating modular inverses.

For example, calculating **7x = 5 (mod 12)**

Which is the same as saying: 7x - 5 = 12k

Which becomes: 7x - 12k = 5

And then I proceed using Euclidean Algorithm for x,k. I get to -25 and 15 respectively. However, I need the x to be positive to get the inverse I'm looking for. How can I get a positive modular inverse?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: note that $7\cdot -25 -12\cdot 15 = -175-180=-355$ while $7\cdot -25 - 12 \cdot -15=5$ so you may want to check your signs.

Comment: **Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 12\!:\ n\equiv n+12\equiv n+24\equiv n+36\equiv \,\ldots\ \ $

Comment: Can’t you just do it by inspection? $7\cdot11=6\cdot12+5$, $11$ is the solution.

Comment: Yeah I got it by inspection, but I'm looking for a way to get it when I can't get there that way. I'm keeping an eye on my EEA and I notice my problem was that i was doing ax+by=d for both positives, when my b is -12 (in this case). I'm doing wrong the negative divisions, I guess (ie, 7/-12?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Bezout identity
$$
a⋅x+b⋅y=c
$$
you can exchange multiples of $a⋅b$ or even $lcm(a,b)=a'\cdot b=a\cdot b'$ between the terms on the left, so that
$$
a⋅(x-k⋅b')+b⋅(y+k⋅a')=c
$$
is also a correct identity. This slightly extends the reasoning on modular equivalences in the comment of  Bill Dubuque.